Why does the terminal close immediately in Code::Blocks?
I downloaded an editor syntax highlighting color theme externally and modified the Code::Blocks configuration. After that, the program terminates immediately as soon as I run it.
Here is a picture of the Code::Blocks AppData folder.
enter image description here


I'm not sold on the duplicate. "the program" referred to by the asker could be Code::Blocks itself. But I'm not reopening the question because it's currently too unclear to be conclusively answered.
